# Automating a Dropbox download in R

Tags: r, dropbox, dropbox-api, rjava

I'm trying to set up an automation via R that will download a CSV file from Dropbox on a weekly basis. I'm using the `retmis` package.

The problem is, there is a part of the naming convention within the URL that changes each time someone uploads a new version of the file into the Dropbox folder.

```
library(retmis)

    customer_id <- source_data("https://www.dropbox.com/s/yeeih34mueagpsx/customer_id_update_20180628_adv.csv?dl=1")
```

It's that middle part which throws a wrench into the automation process: `yeeih34mueagpsx`

It's not going to be the same thing. The prior week it was:

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu5tp0ihplm7dh0/customer_id_update_20180621_adv.csv?dl=1`

(You will notice it gets uploaded every Thursday)

All I know is that it's going to be a 15 character string of letters and numbers.

Is this something can be automated, and if so, how can I go about doing it?

Comment: Try using [rdrop2](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2) which uses the official API to get files from dropbox. What even is the "retmis" package? I can't seem to find it on google.

Answer (score 0):

These strings in the Dropbox shared links are random and not predictable. Every new shared link gets a new string.

There are a few ways you might want to approach this:

a) In your current set up, you include the date in the file name, so each week the upload results in a new file. If you only ever need the current week's data to be available though, and you have control over who or what is doing the uploading, you can instead omit the date from the filename and use the same file name/path every week by overwriting the data each time. If you do this, you can use the same shared link every week, and it will always just return the latest data.

b) If you do need to keep each file though, you can use the Dropbox API to create a new shared link for each new file. To do so, you would use the [/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings). (I don't have sample R code for that, but there is a `curl` example you can translate, or use a third party library.)

c) If you can use the Dropbox API, and don't also need the shared link for something else, you can use the API to access the file data directly without creating a shared link. To do so, you would use [the /2/files/download endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download).